# Required complete example of POST multipart/form-data using CURL and Curlfile()

Tags: php, post, curl, heroku, multipartform-data

I have struggling couple of days now. (Btw, I'm new to cURL)

I have API's setup by my mobile application developer on Heroku where I'm posting form data using following:

```
 public function do_add() {

                $Name           =   $this->input->post('Name');
                $Email          =   $this->input->post('Email');
                $Password       =   $this->input->post('Password');

                $txt             =  "Created";


                $url = 'https://myfullurl.com/api/users/';


                $fields = array(
                    'name'                      =>  $Name,
                    'email'                     =>  $Email,
                    'password'                  =>  $Password,
                    'role'                      =>  'driver'
                );

                $result = $this->scripts->api_add($url, $fields);

                        $this->session->set_userdata('Success',"Record Has Been Successfully ".$txt."...");
                        redirect(base_url().'mmsadmin/users/view_all'); 

  }
```

So when I post data above function of Codeignitor received it and post it to my model function below:

```
 public function api_add($url, $fields){

$fields_string = "";
                //url-ify the data for the POST
                foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
                rtrim($fields_string, '&');

                //open connection
                $ch = curl_init();

                //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->session->userdata('Token')));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                $result = json_decode($content = curl_exec($ch));
                curl_close($ch);

                return $result;

}
```

Above all working fine. Now I need to be able to send a file with it. Have been googling and found some -F command and also sending it using '@' but when I try that my server it give me error that this method is depreciated and I should use curlfile()

Can one of you geniuses out there change my functions to show exactly how to do this. As I'm clueless and running around like headless chicken for two days now :(

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

curl file sending method you are using is depreciated from php5 and you should use curlfile class.

```
    // Create a cURL handle
    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');

    // Create a CURLFile object
    $cfile = new CURLFile('filename.fileTpye');

    // Assign POST data
    curl_file_create('filename.fileTpye');
   // Assign POST data 
    $data =     array('test_file' =>$cfile,'name'=>'test','anotherData'=>'abc');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    // Execute the handle
    curl_exec($ch);
```

above is Object oriented style,another is Procedural style which is mentioned below:

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');

    // Create a CURLFile object
    $cfile = curl_file_create('filename.fileTpye');

    // Assign POST data
    $data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    // Execute the handle
    curl_exec($ch);
```

for more information please see php [curlFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) manual.

Comment: Thanks man, but it's only example of sending a file. How can I send form data as well as file.

My developer said he setup the receiving in a way that he gets the form data and then receive file. But obviously I have to send at a same time

Comment: You can append your data in data array like:


          `$cfile = curl_file_create('filename.fileTpye');
         // Assign POST data
        $data = array('test_file' => $cfile,'name'=>'test','anotherData'=>'abc');`